# Some of the Applications are getting downloaded more than once from Android Market

Tags: google-play-store, 2.1-eclair, downloading

I observed one funny thing. I have the habit of installing the applications directly from Android market on PC.

How to install the Apps directly from PC ?

Ans: I have a Google Account. I open the https://market.android.com/ site on PC and login with my Google Account. I have set this Google Account as  Primary Google Account in my Android Phone. 
Now if I Click on Install of any application on my PC, I can see the same application downloading on my phone's notification bar.

I saw the application 100% downloaded. And I wait for the application to be installed. Of course after downloading the application my phone will automatically installs the application. We need to watch thats it.

But most of the apps are getting downloaded more than once. I don't know why it is happening ? I saw the application downloaded 100%. But again starts a fresh download without doing anything.

I remember while updating the Google Maps and Facebook had the same issue.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, are you downloading from the Market or getting on a PC and side-loading? Which apps are coming twice and which route did they come from originally? How do you know they're downloading more than once, do you have lots of duplicate icons in your app list, or is the notification bar's download notifications, or something else?

Comment: @GAThrawn : Is it clear ? Pl check the updated post.

Comment: Ah ok that's completely different from what I thought your question was about to start with. I often use the Market website to push apps to my phone, and I don't think I've ever seen them try to download themselves twice.

Comment: @GAThrawn : Oh is it ? For me its happening very regularly. I don't know how its happening ? I installed Link2SD which moves the installed applications to the SD Card. I am not sure whether this is causing the issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself got to know why its happening. 
First I selected any application from the **Android Market** and say **Install** and then **Ok**. Its going to start Downloading.

I observed this in two scenarios. Both of the cases are pretty much same.

Case I.
If I **Minimize/Kill** the **Android Market** application while Downloading using the **Back Button** then it completes the Download and Starts the new Download again.

Case II.
I **Minimize/Kill** the Android application while Downloading using the **Back Button** and again open the **Android Market** application, then we can see the same application is getting Downloaded twice from the Market. If we do the same thing again then we can see the application is getting download more than thrice.

The solution is Simple. If any application is getting downloading from the Android Market just press the **Home key** to minimize the **Android Market**.