# How do I force stop an application downloading from Android Market?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

As I posted [Some of the applications are getting downloaded more than once ...](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/some-of-the-applications-are-getting-downloaded-more-than-once-from-android-mark) I need to stop the downloading an application from the Market. Its really waste of time and waste of data(I use 2GB data plan for my mobile).

I restarted the phone, killed the Market app from Task Manager, but still no help. It still continues to download. After complete downloading its going to start download again. For this reason I wanted to stop the Download.

(Android 2.1)

Comment: Did you try clearing the data for the Market app?

Comment: @MatthewRead - No I haven't tried it. How to do that ?

Comment: `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> Market -> Clear data + Clear cache`

Comment: @MatthewRead - There is no Clear Data. But Clear Cache is there and it shows 0.0kB.

Comment: Does "Clear Data" show up if you hit "Force Kill"?

Comment: Still no help. I tried to force kill. But it is not getting stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings... Applications...  Select Filter Options (contains All, Running, Downloaded).

This option can be chosen by clicking left/right option depends upon handset model.

Choose 'All'...so that you can see all applications. Select Download Manager; there you can click 'Clear data' button. It will stop all downloading applications.

Just now I analyzed and found it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a random guess work on fixing your problem, at times I find myself facing this "bug". What I do is connect to wifi and just let it do its thing (download until it stops) then I disconnect and reboot. After that, I don't encounter it anymore. Well, I encountered it twice but that was it.

This is coming from an ICS user btw.

Answer (score 0):

In `Setting > App > Running app > Download manager`, click the `Clear cache` button. The download process will stop.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, this answer seems worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is quite simple actually .You need to erase the downloadmanager's data.

Goto the download manager in Settings->Apps and clear DownloadManager's app data.

Answer (score 0):

The application downloading continuously again and again Is quite annoying and quite common whether you are  using a Data plan(Mobile Data) or Wireless(Wi-Fi). I  had faced the same problem when updating the TrueCaller app on my Android device(4.1.2).The app had installed almost 4-5 times and all the time it installed only 65-70% and also wasted a lot of mobile data.My suggestion is the internet configuration is not proper or there is low network in your area.

**Concept:-**
For the problem to understand there's a small concept of data transfer in the internet.

In the internet there is two basic steps of data transfer

1)Uplink (up arrow) .

2)Downlink(the down arrow).

First the request will be sent to the server through an uplink. Next the server responds by sending the data through the downlink(in the form of packets).

You can see this when you are browsing the net there is alternative downlink and uplink of data and packets are transferred internally(you cannot see which packet is transferred and when but only confirm if all are received through a successful login or complete download).For this you will require a good network around you

If any one packet is lost/missing ( during downlink or uplink) then the play store keeps trying to update the app until you reach 100% of installation and you cannot stop the update until and unless you boot your device or click stop(Sometime even stop does not function) or even close your mobile data.

**Solution:-**

1. For this  switch off the connection(Mobile Data/Wi-Fi) for a while .
2. Make sure all the settings are correctly configured.(Plan is active,
   having appropriate balance ,good network reach etc.)
3. Then switch on Mobile Data wait for the connection to be
   established and check for an app whether it is installing or not. If yes then you can update you app which was getting re-installed every time. 
   If you still face the problem then in the app page scroll to the bottom where you will find a support mail id and contact them with your problem as well as a screen shot.
   Once the app is updated then you shall not face any
   problem regarding constant re-install in the.